# Why GDAL is not running in Python 3.7.2 powershell

Tags: python, gdal

[image]

I installed GDAL 2.4.0 core and GDAL-2.4.0.win32-py3.7 to run my code but it is not working

Comment: what is your path set to?

Comment: which path setting sir??

Comment: Please [Edit] your question so that the error message is in the body ***as text***. This makes it legible on all devices and searchable by others.

Answer (score 1):

If it says `No module named ...`, it's usually not the installation of GDAL itself that is corrupted / missing, but rather that the Python package failed to install or has been installed with another Python version.

In case you want to go the *hard* way, see if `pip` points to the same Python distribution as `python` to make sure you install for the same Python distribution. Also take care that there are no errors during this installation.

Otherwise, install conda (https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html; install with `conda install gdal` then, which should include a GDAL installation) or take the wheel from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal, which already includes a complete GDAL installation. You can then install via `pip install GDAL‑2.3.3‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl`.

Comment: If you're going to use conda, i recommend grabbing gdal et al from the conda-forge channel (`conda install gdal rasterio geopandas --channel=conda-forge`). that way, conda can manage the dependencies rather than the user.